# Duplicate environment in a workspace

Tags: postman

I was just exploring postman when I found out that it is possible to create two environments with the same name in a workspace. Is it the expected behavior? I think it could lead to conflicts in variables , etc

Answer (score 1):

I think it is expected because of 2 reasons:

- Each environment has unique `id`
- In postman UI, you can only choose one environment at a time.